# Why does Recycle Bin say 16 but I only have 15 items?

Tags: recycle-bin

From the Site Contents page the Recycle Bin has 16 next to it. However, when I go into the Recycle Bin there are only 15 items. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you dont have permission to see others document.

If you are site collection admin then you can everything in both 1st and 2nd stage recyclebin.

Comment: Thank you. I notice you use the term "site collection administrator." Is a "site collection administrator" The administrator for the entire SharePoint account, or only one of the Administrator titles.   In addition, what do you mean by 1st and 2nd stage recycle bin?

Comment: I mean administrator of site collection, one who can can access everything in a given site collection. One who can access entire sharepoint called farm admin.  Check this for recycle bin https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-restore-or-delete-items-in-the-Recycle-Bin-of-a-SharePoint-site-6df466b6-55f2-4898-8d6e-c0dff851a0be

Comment: Why do the call it "farm" admin? Thanks for the link.

Comment: becuase they manage the SharePoint farm. SharePoint consist on multiple components( server[s]), when one install sharepoint, sql server etc and configure the envirnoment then that is called SharePoint farm. The user who manage sharepoint farm called Farm adminsitrator. that's a permission level in sharepoint

Comment: Interesting. Forgive me for my perceived ignorance on the subject. But why do the use the term "farm"? Is this a technical term in general?

Comment: yes it is. This is not new word, almost every technology is using this term. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180939/what-is-a-farm-in-sharepoint